# will + to + noun?

Tags: meaning

I don't remember any case that noun ***will*** is followed by preposition ***to***. So I look it up in a number of dictionaries to no avail. Maybe I missed the definition that fits with it. I think noun ***will*** means ***the determination to do something***, as the Collins English Dictionary says, but in this definition is ***will*** followed by preposition ***to*** as well as infinitive ***to***?

> Even the most respectable of all musical institutions, the symphony
> orchestra, carries inside its DNA the legacy of the hunt. The various
> instruments in the orchestra can be traced back to these primitive
> origins — their earliest forms were made either from the animal (horn,
> hide, gut, bone) or the weapons employed in bringing the animal under
> control (stick, bow). Are we wrong to hear this history in the music
> itself, in the formidable aggression and awe-inspiring assertiveness
> of those monumental symphonies that remain the core repertoire of the
> world’s leading orchestras? Listening to Beethoven, Brahms, Mahler,
> Bruckner, Berlioz, Tchaikovsky, Shostakovich, and other great
> composers, I can easily summon up images of bands of men embarking on
> the hunt, using sound as a source and symbol of dominance, an
> expression of ***the will to predatory power*** (although, with
> Shostakovich, it is sometimes hard to tell whether he is extending
> that tradition or merely satirizing it).

[Music: A Subversive History](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=0NeIDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT28&lpg=PT28&dq=Are%20we%20wrong%20to%20hear%20this%20history%20in%20the%20music%20itself,%20in%20the%20formidable%20aggression%20and%20awe%20inspiring%20assertiveness%20of%20those%20monumental%20symphonies%20that%20remain%20the%20core%20repertoire%20of%20the%20world%E2%80%99s%20leading%20orchestras?&source=bl&ots=Krtv6D5u54&sig=ACfU3U0Awb5vBvFe1TC5JZEXB8qXWcxaJg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSipHB0cr2AhWCaN4KHT73CukQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=Are%20we%20wrong%20to%20hear%20this%20history%20in%20the%20music%20itself%2C%20in%20the%20formidable%20aggression%20and%20awe%20inspiring%20assertiveness%20of%20those%20monumental%20symphonies%20that%20remain%20the%20core%20repertoire%20of%20the%20world%E2%80%99s%20leading%20orchestras%3F&f=false)

Comment: There are *hundreds* of written instances of the sequence [***his will to power***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+will+to+power%22) in Google Books, and I'd guess few if any of them are using ***power*** as a verb (with ***to*** simply being the infinitive marker). So clearly the fact that you *don't remember any case that noun **will** is followed by preposition **to*** is more to do with what you've noticed and remembered, rather than what usages actually occur in English. What was the question?

Comment: **The will to power** is a phrase that comes from [the writings of Friedrich Nietzsche](https://www.thoughtco.com/nietzsches-concept-of-the-will-to-power-2670658) and means something like "the desire for mastery or domination."   It's a translation of the German *der Wille zur Macht*, which may explain why the phrasing is unusual.  You are unlikely to ever find "the will to *noun*" in any other phrasing.

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I remember I encountered 'the will to power,' which comes from Nietzsche. Pardon my poor memory. Thanks stangdon and FumbleFingers!